# how to draw route when user click on marker

Tags: google-maps, flutter

i am working on google map[image: look this image] flutter and i added multiple markers on map. so i want to draw route between user location and the marker clicked

```
 for (int i = 0; i < lat.length; i++) {
  _markerIdCounter++;
  markerId = MarkerId('marker_id_$_markerIdCounter');
  
  double la = lat[i];
  double lo = long[i];
  destPosition = LatLng(la, lo);
  address = await geolocator.placemarkFromCoordinates(
      destPosition.latitude, destPosition.longitude);
  Placemark place = address[0];
  _markers.add(Marker(
      markerId: markerId,
      position: destPosition,
      icon: destinationIcon,
      infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: place.name.toString()),
      onTap: () {
        var options;
        _onMarkerTapped(markerId);
        LatLng des = destPosition;
        LatLng cu =
            LatLng(currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude);
        getDistanceTime(cu, destPosition);
        setPolylines(destPosition);
      }));
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the google maps directions API that will return you a **ROUTE** object that contains everything you may need to draw the path(polyline) based on the props you've sent to it( for example str address A to str address B or lat long A to lat long B etc...).  [Click here for full API doc ref](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/routes/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=FY18-Q2-global-demandgen-paidsearchonnetworkhouseads-cs-maps_contactsal_saf&utm_content=text-ad-none-none-DEV_c-CRE_397052992493-ADGP_Hybrid%20%7C%20AW%20SEM%20%7C%20SKWS%20%7E%20Routes%20%7C%20BMM%20%7C%20Directions%20API-KWID_43700049595992169-aud-903284320020:kwd-445998650286-userloc_1001464&utm_term=KW_%2Bdirections%20%2Bapi-ST_%2Bdirections%20%2Bapi&gclid=CjwKCAjw4rf6BRAvEiwAn2Q76hiD8dX_ZJn4RzNqzZ6UJJxjTTOEMdS7_lihSTOufdAqIzWnMb9cNBoCS4sQAvD_BwE)

Comment: isn't Possible to get the clicked marker id or latlong?

Comment: I think it will be best if you use lat lng, Check the Google API documentation to figure out what is the best approach for your case.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [flutter_polyline_points](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_polyline_points) package. It's a plugin the uses Google Maps Directions API to show route/polylines on maps. Make sure you have a [valid API key and Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/get-api-key) enabled on your Google cloud console to use it.

You can create a method that accepts latlng coordinates of your marker and then call that method every time you click the marker. Kindly check out the examples in the package doc for more details.